# how to troubleshoot using the node.js GOT http request library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, hasura, node.js-got

I have some code using GOT querying a graphQL endpoint:

```
// set up params for call to weather cache 
    const queryQL = `
      query weather {
        weather(where: {idLatLong: {_eq: "${latLong}"}}) {
          id
          idLatLong
          updated_at
          lat
          long
          requestedByUserId
          data
          created_at
        }
      }
    `
    const query = {query: queryQL};
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'X-Hasura-Admin-Secret': process.env.HASURA_KEY
      },
      responseType: 'json'
    }

    // see if there's an existing record for the lat long
    try {
      const response = await got.post(process.env.GQL_ENDPOINT, query, options);
      console.log('query weather hasura');
      console.log(response.body);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

I am getting a response from Hasura `{"errors":[{"extensions":{"path":"$","code":"invalid-headers"},"message":"Missing Authorization header in JWT authentication mode"}]}`

How do I see what GOT is sending out to the GQL endpoint? FYI, this call works fine in the GQL console and also in Postman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `got()` library has hooks that allow you to see the headers it's about to send.  Here's an example that you can run and then insert the same thing into your code:

```
const got = require('got');

got("http://www.google.com", {
    hooks: {
        beforeRequest: [function(options) {
            console.log(options);
        }]
    }
}).then(result => {
    let i = 1;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can also get a network analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to put on your client computer and watch the actual network traffic.